# Application Context in Non Activity Class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-context

There is alot of info on this topic but none of it assist me.
I have several global variables/fields inside the app's application class:

```
public class App extends Application {

private static App instance

public string PUBNUB_SUB = BuildConfig.PUBNUB_SUB_KEY; 
public string PUBNUB_PUB = BuildConfig.PUBNUB_PUB_KEY;


public void onCreate() {
instance = this;

}

public static App getInstance(){
   return instance;
}

}
```

In Activities/Fragments I'm successfully accessing those variables like so:

```
class ActivityA extend Activity {

App baseApp;
Pubnub pubnub;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

     baseApp = new(App)getApplicationContext();
     Pubnub(baseApp.PUBNUB_SUB, baseApp.PUBNUB_PUB)

}
```

Now How do I access getApplicationContext() in a non-Activity/non-Fragment Class?

```
 public class Events {


 App baseApp;
 Context mContext;
 app = new(LoQooApp)mContext.getApplication(); ???


 public Events(Context context) {
 app = new(LoQooApp)mContext.getApplication(); ???
 }
```

The above doesnt work, where should

app = new(LoQooApp) getApplication(); go?

Comment: What? you can always pass Context in constructor, if you are in fragment getActivity() will get you the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `PUBNUB_SUB` and `PUBNUB_PUB` are constants, so you could declare them as `public static final` and then access using a static reference: `App.PUBNUB_SUB` and `App.PUBNUB_PUB`